# SSRS Page break on Tablix with Rownumber ,just one row group and no group expression given by default

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report with one tablix and it has one RowGroup (which automatically came) when I dragged and dropped my report fields. [It doesnot have any group by expression defined]

Now my requirement is to create page breaks based on the row number.

**I clicked on the RowGroup properties and give Group on expression
=Floor(RowNumber(Nothing)-1/2000)**

And page break "Between each instance of group "

Now page is breaking,but the problem is its breaking for every row in my tablix.

How can I overcome the same and break only at 2000 rows.

**This is to avoid Excel export exception on large data.**

What am I doing wrong with the tablix/group settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done this before but try adding another group outside you current group with this expression. Then set the page break in it.

Edit: I just re read you question. I think you expression is incorrect. I think it should be:

```
=Floor((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/2000)
```

I couldn't understand how you could set that as the group expression and it would stil group correctly. So you will still need 2 groups:

1. An outside group with this expression and the pagebreak.
2. A details group with what you are actual displaying on each row.

Comment: that also is showing the same result. Tabix->RowGroup and should change to Tablix->GroupPageBReak->RowGroup?

Comment: Jim.Thanks for the solution.Now one more issue,the page break is causing unwanted blank pages in the pdf export of the report. I didnt change any width settings or included any new components.I just introduced one more group into the tablix and that is causing the issue.

Comment: Is the extra goup in the tablix making it wider? or Are you getting page breaks when there are no inner group rows?

Comment: Careless :( . I introduced the group and that caused the increase in width,then I removed the column.But the increased width,I didnt change. So now its fixed.