# Add Paging to a SSRS Tablix in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I currently have a report that consists of a single table/tablix that contains company name, year 1 revenue, and year 2 revenue. The table is sorted by year 1 revenue descending. The report often returns several hundred company names however. Is there a way to only display 10 records at a time and enable a paging option to then move on to the next group? I am using Report Builder 3.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200628/ssrs-page-break-on-tablix-with-rownumber-just-one-row-group-and-no-group-expres and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003153/how-to-add-ssrs-page-break-after-65536-rows-counting-group-header-footer

Answer (score -2):

1. Create a row group on your "details" row and hide it. Set the group on to:

   Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing))

It basically assigns whole numbers 1,2,3..to every consecutive chunk of 10 records.

2. Next, in the page break options configure the page to break at the end of every instance of group.

Ta-da! Pagination done.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't quite right as it gives each individual returned row an individual group number and its paginating on each unique number